# What is the difference between using a function to initialise a JavaScript object with and without return statement?

Tags: javascript

I have two functions to initialise objects. init and differentInit.

```
function init(){
    return {a:5};
}

function differentInit(){
    this.a =5;
}

obj = init();
newobj = new differentInit()
```

how are the objects obj and newobj different?
This is what the JavaScript interpreter shows as the contents of the two objects.

```
>obj
<·Object {a: 5}
>newobj
<·differentInit {a: 5}
```

EDIT: As the answers (which are really good) have pointed out that `newobj` has an additional prototype as `differentInit.prototype`. I had thought an object can only be created with an additional prototype using the `Object.create()` method. I don't know if this a far too generic question, but how many other ways are there to create objects with prototypes? And can the method used in this question be considered a good way to create an object with prototypes?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> how are the objects obj and newobj different?

Given the functions you've shown, the only real difference is that the second one has an extra prototype (with a different `constructor` property) between it and `Object.prototype`. The first one directly inherits from `Object.prototype`:

E.g., `obj`:

```
                                  +----------+
Object.prototype-------------+--->| toString |
                             |    | valueOf  |
                             |    | ...      |
                             |    +----------+
        +---------------+    |
obj---->| [[Prototype]] |----+
        | a: 5          |
        +---------------+
```

vs. `newObj`:

```
                                                           +----------+
Object.prototype--------------------------------------+--->| toString |
                                                      |    | valueOf  |
                                                      |    | ...      |
                                                      |    +----------+
                                  +---------------+   |
differentInit.prototype------+--->| [[Prototype]] |---+
                             |    +---------------+
                             |
                             |
        +---------------+    |
newObj->| [[Prototype]] |----+
        | a: 5          |
        +---------------+
```

*(Note that as [Oriol points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35223757/157247), the objects that `Object.prototype` and `differentInit.prototype` point to both have a `constructor` property that points to `Object` and `differentInit` respectively. So `obj.constructor` will be `Object` and `newObj.constructor` will be `differentInit`. I'd've added it to the diagrams, but it complicates them unnecessarily...)*

Unless you add something to `differentInit.prototype`, it doesn't make any significant practical difference.

---

Since you've tagged your question `json`, I'll just note that there's no JSON being used anywhere in your question. JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. If you're dealing with program source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

---

> I always thought an object can only be created with a prototype using the `Object.create()` method.

In JavaScript, all objects have prototypes unless they're created with `Object.create(null)` (which gives them `null` in their `[[Prototype]]` internal slot, e.g., they have no prototype).

> ...how many other ways are there to create objects with prototypes?

You can *create* objects with prototypes by:

1. Using an object initializer, e.g. `obj = {}`, which creates it using `Object.prototype` as its prototype.
2. By using the `new` operator with a function; the object that the function's `prototype` property refers to is assigned as the prototype of the object that `new` creates. All functions created with the `function` (or `class`) keyword get a `prototype` property with a blank object on it; that can then be added to, or replaced. (If the function's `prototype` is `null`, `new` uses `Object.prototype` instead.)

   Note that the function you use with `new` can either be any function defined using the `function` keyword:

   ```
   // Using `function`
   function Foo() {
   }
   Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
       console.log("Foo instance says 'bar'!");
   };
   var f = new Foo();
   f.bar();
   ```

   or as of ES2015, a function defined with the `class` keyword:

   ```
   class Foo {
       bar() {
           console.log("Foo instance says 'bar'!");
       }
   }
   var f = new Foo();
   f.bar();
   ```

   Barring a couple of minor details, the two snippets above do the same thing: They define a function called `Foo`, which you are expected to call via `new`, which has `Foo.prototype` with `bar` on it.
3. Using `Object.create(p)`, where `p` is assigned as the resulting object's prototype. Unlike #2 above, `p` can be `null` to create an object that doesn't have a prototype. This was added in ES5, although it can be shimmed (other than the `null` bit). (There's an optional second argument that can't be shimmed.)

You can *set* an object's prototype after creation in two ways:

1. Using [`Reflect.setPrototypeOf(target, proto)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-reflect.setprototypeof) or the very similar [`Object.setPrototypeOf(target, proto)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.setprototypeof), which are new in ES2015. (The only difference between them is that `Reflect.setPrototypeOf` will throw if you pass it a non-object as `target`; `Object.setPrototypeOf` will just return what you gave it unchanged in that case. That, and some JavaScript engines don't have the `Reflect` object yet, but will soon.)
2. (Backward compat only) Using the [`__proto__` property](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-object.prototype.__proto__), provided that the object inherits (directly or indirectly) from `Object.prototype`. **Notes:**

   A. This is specified for JavaScript engines in web browsers only.

   B. It was not part of the specification before ES2015.

   C. Since it wasn't in the spec until ES2015, is only defined on web browsers, and will fail if the object doesn't inherit from `Object.prototype`, in the **very rare** case you need to dynamically set an object's prototype *after* creating it, use `Reflect.setPrototypeOf` instead.

> And can the method used in this question be considered a good way to create an object with prototypes?

If by "the method" you mean `new differentInit`, yes, that's a completely normal way to create an object with a specific prototype. Typically you use that form when you're going to create *several* objects (a "class" of objects in the general sense of the word; e.g., objects that have a majority of traits in common). It's also perfectly normal and fine to use `Object.create` for that use case (some people don't like to use the `new` operator at all). If you're just doing a one-off where you want a specific object to inherit from another specific object, `Object.create` is the way to go.

Comment: How come you only answer those question which are tricky to understand and provide solution of ?

Comment: @RayonDabre: :-) Oh, I'm fairly indiscriminate. It's almost Pavlovian: "Oh! Oh! I know that one!"

Comment: this explains it :) I've edited the question to have a couple of follow up questions. Could you please take a look at that too? And thanks, I'll remove the JSON tag.

Comment: @jeffpc1993: Those are really *different* questions. Questions on SO are meant to be individual. But I've added to the answer above.

Comment: Thanks. I'll keep that in mind for future questions.

Comment: @Oriol: True, added.

Answer (score 4):

The most practical differences are

```js
obj.constructor === Object
newobj.constructor === differentInit
```

```js
Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) === Object.prototype;
Object.getPrototypeOf(newobj) === differentInit.prototype;
```

```js
obj instanceof differentInit === false
newobj instanceof differentInit === true
```

Otherwise (unless you modify `differentInit.prototype`), they are basically the same.